# Self Signed Certificate Working for IdentityServer on CurrentUser, but not LocalMachine

Tags: c#, certificate, identityserver4, x509certificate

Using the Powershell command `New-SelfSignedCertificate` I've generated a certificate for use with Identity Server.  My Powershell command looked like this:

```
PS> New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=mycert" -KeySpec "Signature" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\localMachine\My\" -NotAfter "12/12/2021"
```

(For the user cert, I used `Cert:\CurrentUser\My\`)

The Identity Server code looks like this:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
using (X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
        X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
        thumbprint,
        true);

    if (certCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        cert = certCollection[0];                    
    }
}

services
    .AddIdentityServer()
    //.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddSigningCredential(cert)
    ...
```

For the user cert, I used `StoreLocation.CurrentUser`.  When I run the user cert, it works fine, but on the local machine cert (I checked in MMC, it does install the cert correctly) it doesn't find a valid cert.  Just to be clear, if I change:

```
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
    thumbprint,
    true);
```

to:

```
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
    thumbprint,
    false);
```

Then it does find the cert, but it's obviously not valid.  Please can anyone tell me why this is so?

Comment: do still need help ?

Comment: It's still an outstanding question